# How can I provide a keystore password on startup to tomcat without using a system property?

Tags: tomcat

I'd like to be able to deliver a preconfigured server.xml file for tomcat that has a placeholder for the SSL keystore password. My understanding is that one can use system properties inside the server.xml files like so:

```
<Connector port="443"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           acceptorThreadCount="2"
           connectionTimeout="10000"
           maxKeepAliveRequests="${max.keepAlive}"
           maxThreads="${max.threads}"
           maxExtensionSize="65536"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           scheme="https"
           secure="true"
           clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreType="PKCS12"
           keystoreFile="/var/certs/mycert.p12"
           keystorePass="${keystore.pass}" />
```

I can then provide a system property by setting CATALINA_OPTS to something like `"$CATALINA_OPTS -Dkeystore.pass=supersecret"`.

This technically work, however; this will cause the keystore pass to leak into the process list. That is, if I were to execute `ps -Af | grep java` I can see where I passed in my system property.

So how do I provide the password to server.xml external of the config without using a system property?